# Type erasure in swing.event.ListSelectionChanged

Tags: swing, scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure

Why do I get a pattern matcher warning regarding type erasure with the following Scala Swing code:

```
import scala.swing._

object Test extends ListView(Seq(1, 2, 3)) {
  listenTo(selection)
  reactions += {
    case event.ListSelectionChanged(_, range, _) => println(range)
  }
}
```

The warning is:

```
warning: non variable type-argument A in type pattern
scala.swing.event.ListSelectionChanged[A] is unchecked 
since it is eliminated by erasure
             case event.ListSelectionChanged(_, range, _) => println(range)
                                            ^
```

Is this just horrible design of Scala Swing, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's a scala swing problem. Scala swing is just another started-but-never-finished scala library.

Comment: I can do away with the warning by using a type check (with wildcard) instead of extractor. `case l: event.ListSelectionChanged[ _ ] => println( l.range )`. But I think the idea was to have the case class extractor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has disappeared with the new Scala 2.10 pattern matcher.